# Windows Forms Side panel with Split Horizontal Panels Layout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout

So I have been trying to make this layout. So far I have been able to do the 1st panel using the *DockStyle.Left*. However when I try to add the 2nd it keeps overlapping the 1st one. Also what would be the best way to add/manage the panels so when I add the 3rd one both panels get half of the UI height.

[image]

I'd like to avoid to use Drop and Drag tool.

Code with my panels so far:

```
Panel backPanel = new Panel();
backPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Panel panel1 = new Panel();
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;

Panel panel2 = new Panel();
panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
panel2.BackColor = Color.Cyan;

backPanel.Controls.Add(panel1);
backPanel.Controls.Add(panel2);
this.Controls.Add(backPanel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Controls are docked in their Z-order, which is the visual layering of controls on a form along the form's Z-axis (depth).* 
>   <sub><sup>[[Docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)</sup></sub>

So the order of adding controls to the container is important. For example, for getting your expected layout you can add controls in this other:

```
var panel1 = new Panel() { BackColor = Color.Red, Dock = DockStyle.Left };
var panel2 = new Panel() { BackColor = Color.Green, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
var panel3 = new Panel() { BackColor = Color.Blue, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
this.Controls.AddRange(new[] { panel3, panel2, panel1 });
```

**Note:**

- Don't avoid using designer of Windows Forms, unless you are creating some dynamic UI at run-time based on a custom logic.
- If you are using designer, you can simply use *Document Outline* window to change z-index of control. To show the window, go to *View → Other Windows → Document Outline*.
- If you are using designer, you can use *Send to Back* and *Bring to Front* commands from *Layout Toolbar* or by right click on the control.
- Using code, you can use `SendToBack` and `BringToFrom` method of the control to bring it in front or send it to back of all controls.
- Using code, you can use `SetChildIndex` method of the container control to set the z-index of the control.
- As another option, you can mix two `SplitContainer` controls.